# IE8, FF3 <img> Align Center Issue

Tags: html, css, image

I am encountering a strange bug in IE and Firefox where an image will not center align. As the page is loading the image centers but then mysteriously shifts to the left as the page loads!  I have the following set as CSS:

```
#image{
display: block; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}
```

And the HTML markup:

```
<img id="image" src="example.png" width="158" height="167" alt="Example">
```

**Note** that in Chrome and Safari I am not experiencing this bug.

**Update:** The image does not have a parent, save for a container class that has `min-width: 850px` and `width: 100%` attributes. There is an image to the far right of this image but is absolutely positioned. There is a header element directly above the image, but whose `margin-bottom` is set to zero.

**Update**: There is a header which is causing the problem which has the following CSS:

```
#header {

                padding: 5px;
                height: 20px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                background: #333333;
            }
```

Comment: There may be other factors involved. Can you provide more context?

Comment: Sure. I will provide more context in my answer.

Comment: How about margin:0 auto;

Comment: user1193749, I tried that already and it produces the same undesired effect. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate your code here. The image is aligned to the center.

http://jsfiddle.net/fSueu/

Could you give me more details if I miss anything?

Comment: This is theoretically how it should be presented. But I am having a  difficult time isolating the problem because of there are so many other elements. When I position the image above the header of the page it centers. Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: I updated your code. Now when I insert a header it is decentering! This is the problem! Hopefully, a solution becomes clearer to us.

Comment: I could not find your code. Is your code like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fSueu/7/ Please click the "update" button at the top after your edit the code.

Comment: It was the header, as I suspected. I set the header to `position: fixed;` and then added some padding to the image to prevent overlap with the header. Now it works. This is a weird issue. Thank you guys, for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {
    text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 20px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #333333;
        }
```

Center align text in the container and the image will center align in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do easily as like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="wraptocenter due">
<span></span>
<img width="101" height="101" alt="" src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/5200000/Animated-mermaid-images-mermaids-5260155-313-313.gif">
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.wraptocenter {
    background:red;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/zPQ9M/

More info abut center http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html